# How to start and stop a shell daemon from Ruby

Tags: ruby

How would I start a shell daemon and then stop it from within the same Ruby script?

To be more specific, I'd like my Ruby script to:

- start a server daemon with a shell command (`rails server` | `shotgun` | etc... ).
- do a couple things while the server is running.
- make the server quit.

All embracing solutions that are supported in ruby 1.8/1.9 and unix/windows are preferred. (I read `fork` for instance does not work on Windows).

Comment: I am not sure that your assumption that Kernel::fork does not work on Windows is correct. I would spend some time experimenting with Kernel::exec, Kernel::fork, Kernel::system and see how they behave for you.

Comment: Jordan, I don't use Windows. I just stumbled into multiple mentions of fork not behaving as expected on windows (like here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215939).

Answer (score 3):

I can highly recommend the [Ruby Daemons gem](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/). I think it has all the functionality you need.

Check the section 3 of its README, and pay particular attention to [Daemons.call](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/classes/Daemons.html#M000006) method that allows to daemonize arbitrary code (in which you could just `Kernel.system` an app).

Comment: @Pavel: erm, yes, section 3 of the docs: "Control a bunch of daemons from another application"... Yes it is partly for daemonizing, but also for daemonizing other apps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's similar problem with working solution that uses windows command line:

https://serverfault.com/questions/35305/cmd-exe-how-to-starts-a-background-process-run-some-things-stops-background-pr

This is quite dirty, but it does the trick.

Use Linux if you can, or just bash with basic command line tools (installed with Git for Windows).  With bash, solution is very simple:

```
./script/rails server --pid server.pid &
ruby do_your_stuff.rb
kill `cat server.pid`
```

P.S. Windows is not recommended environment for Rails anyway.  You'll likely save much time in the long run by switching to Linux, becuase you won't be solving odd environmental problems like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do what I needed with the Ruby Daemons gem Peter suggested, and ended up using [systemu](https://github.com/ahoward/systemu) instead:

```
# command to start daemon
command = "thin start" # here starting thin server as example
status, stdout, stderr = systemu command do |cid|
  # do stuff here
  # ...

  Process.kill 9, cid # kill the daemon
end
```

Comment: To use the Daemons gem with Rails you should use the daemon_generator plugin. http://douglasfshearer.com/blog/cron-jobs-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Raad gem (Ruby as a Daemon) https://github.com/colinsurprenant/raad - it will work transparently with MRI Ruby and JRuby. (I am the author).